# How to make a field required in all children in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Suppose I have a class `Base`, how do I make all children inherited from `Base` implements a certain field on its own?

For example, `Base` has a required member function `func()`, `A` extends `Base` and `B` extends `A`. I want to make `func()` **definition required** in both `A` and `B`.

Can I do this and how? Thanks!

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky Yes exactly.

Comment: Already got that before your comment :) Sorry for deletion

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make definition required you have to use interfaces:

```
interface MyPerfectlyNamedInterface {
  func(): any; // no definition here, since interfaces are inherently abstract
}

class Base implements MyPerfectlyNamedInterface {
  func(): any { /* definition is required */ }
}

// note that A does _not_ extend Base
class A implements MyPerfectlyNamedInterface {
  func(): any { /* definition is required */ }
}

class B implements MyPerfectlyNamedInterface {
  func(): any { /* definition is required */ }
}
```

However, if child class extends base class that has definition for your function (e.g., if `A` would extend `Base` and/or `B` would extend `A`), then definition is again not required:

```
interface MyPerfectlyNamedInterface {
  func(): any;
}

class Base implements MyPerfectlyNamedInterface {
  func(): any { /* definition is required */ }
}

// note that A _does_ extend Base
class A extend Base implements MyPerfectlyNamedInterface {
  func(): any { /* definition is not required */ }
}

class B extend A implements MyPerfectlyNamedInterface {
  func(): any { /* definition is not required */ }
}
```

So, I guess, that's not really possible with your setup.

---

Also, you can *sort of* achieve this using `abstract` classes, but again, it won't "cascade" down to child classes as you want:

```
abstract class Base {
  abstract func(): any;
}

class A extends Base {
  func(): any { /* definition is required */ }
}

class B extends A {
  func(): any { /* definition is not required */ }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dima, but casecade is exactly what I want...

Comment: I guess, this isn't currently possible :(

Comment: Actually what I want is, when someone create a class `C` extends my `A` or `B` or `Base`, he would know that he should define a `func()` for `C`. He probably won't add a `implements` statement himself I suppose. T_T

Comment: That could be achieved only with flat inheritance structure (no children of the child), and if base class is `abstract`. Otherwise - sorry

Comment: Also note that `class Base { func(): any {} }` inherently implements `MyPerfectlyNamedInterface`. The `implements` keyword is useful for writing the class but it doesn't impact type.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the method abstract in base class like this.

```
abstract class Base {
  abstract func(): void;
}

class A extends Base {
  func(): void {
    console.log("Doing something in A class");
  }
}

class B extends Base {
  func(): void {
    console.log("Doing something in B class");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Berk, but class `B` is supposed to extends `A` not `Base`.